# Translating form collection input values to hide true values from users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, activerecord

I have a form input on which an algorithm will depend.  I'd rather not expose the actual value to the users since it will unnecessarily reveal some business logic.  I'm currently using a helper options_for_val1 hash with the dropdown text as key and values as [1,2,3,4,5], which are not the values I ultimately need for the algorithm.  My form is:

```
=f.select :val1, options_for_val1, :prompt => 'Select One'
```

Is there a smart way to translate the 1-5 values submitted by the form to the actual values I need? Like some type of validator?

Comment: `before_save :translate_values`

Comment: Ah yes, then `options_for_val1 = [1,2,3,4,5]` and `real_options_for_val1 = [60,70,80,90,100]`, I could set `val1 = real_options_for_val1[options_for_val1.index(val1)]`?

Comment: Something like that, yes.